# react-native run-ios Build Fail: CompileC RCTBaseTextInputView.o

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

How to fix this build failure in ios?
I'm using Xcode Version 9.2
Mac OS Sierra

What is RCTBaseTextInputView?

> CompileC
>   /Users/bliss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNJyotish-fjjxyvwbhqivjwbnwwqhmqzgfazq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTBaseTextInputView.o
>   /Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/ReactNative/RNCLI/BITBUCKET/rnjyotish/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/TextInput/RCTBaseTextInputView.m
>   normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

Comment: If you have solved it, please share. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to solve it directly....my computer is a Early 2011 MacBookPro and the Xcode that can be installed in that machine is very behind to its latest version.  I decided to rent a Mac in Cloud machine and create and compile a new project there with the same code..

Comment: I was able to run it on mac High Sierra 10.13.3 late 2012. It was a painful experience

Comment: Can you share how you made that work please? I had to pay 20+$ per month for the Cloud...I'd rather use my local machine as much as possible....

Answer (score 0):

Each and Every version really matters. This may be done other way for another version. But for Mac **High Sierra** follow this:

My System:

```
High Sierra 10.13.3
XCode 9.4 
Node 8.11.1
react-native-cli@2.0.1
watchman 4.9.0
react-native@57.8
android studio 3.6.3
Android Emulator: Pixel API 28 : Android Pie 9
Also Tested: Genymotion 3.1.0 : Samsung Galaxy S10 Android 10
Iphone Emulator 11.3
```

Xcode Build location **Unique**: xcode -> Preference->Locations -> Advanced

[If you do not installed nvm then uninstall node completely then install it through nvm. It is not required but highly recommended]

```
nvm install 8.11.1
```

THIS VERSION DOES NOT REQUIRE yarn. So I deleted yarn cause later version was making trouble for yarn,
You may try with yarn if it is already installed but for this build not required

```
brew uninstall yarn
brew install watchman
```

do not use npx rather you are going toward particular version

```
npm install -g react-native-cli@2.0.1

add react-native to .bash_profile:
export PATH="/Users/hasan/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/:$PATH"
```

*if you have used oracle java over version 8, uninstall that with the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk
```

Install openJDK8:

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

ALWAYS USE VERSION NUMBER. REACT NATIVE DOESN'T FIX ANYTHING MAGICALLY

```
react-native init RealmProject --version 0.57.8
```

Install android sdk: 
http://reactnative.dev/docs/0.57/getting-started

Add the following to .bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/hasan/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

After above complete successfully:

```
react-native run-android
react-native run-ios
```

if you had any error MAKE SURE you delete all caches:

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```

up to this point there will be no problem but to make it more protected:

Change gradle-wrapper.properties 4.4 to 4.9 under `Project>android>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wraper.properties:`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip

android>build.gradle plugin version change to 3.2.1
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Cheers and Happy Coding!